# Getting an error persistence.xml while implementing Hibernate JPA for an always encrypted mssql database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

When I run my java file I get 2 errors:

1. > [Fatal Error] :25:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
   > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   > Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
2. > Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unexpected error parsing [file:/E:/Netbeans%20Repo/Hibernate/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml]

I'll be posting the persistence.xml file here. Hopefully, the community will be able to help me out.

```XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
  <!-- Define a name used to get an entity manager. Define that you will
    complete transactions with the DB  -->
  <persistence-unit name="Hibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- Define the class for Hibernate which implements JPA -->
    <!-- Define the object that should be persisted in the database -->
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.mycompany.hibernate.Customer</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <!-- Driver for DB database -->
      <!-- URL for DB -->
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
       <!-- URL for DB -->
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value= "jdbc:sqlserver://APPDEV1\BETA:49397;user=TSS\parikshit.phukan;databaseName=SmallOffice;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled " />
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The full error is as follows:
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unexpected error parsing [file:/E:/Netbeans%20Repo/Hibernate/target/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:450)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:249)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:240)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:234)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:68)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:445)
... 10 more
Exception in thread "main" [ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

Comment: Could you put the whole error stack trace

Comment: try changing the version to `2.2` and `persistence_2_2.xsd` as well.

Comment: BJ5 this is the full error that I get: